# Problem in plotting the equation

Tags: plotting, debugging

```
a1 = -0.005461274594969229` Cos[0.7873247600956254` x] + 
   0.007892948842679284` Cosh[0.7873247600956254` x] + 
   0.7086546042035011` Sin[0.7873247600956254` x] - 
   0.007922030707034955` Sinh[0.7873247600956254` x];
a2 = -1.0940399583916758`*^-16 Cos[0.7873247600956254` x] - 
  1.0940399583916758`*^-16 Cosh[0.7873247600956254` x] + 
  0.7055202133840153` Sin[0.7873247600956254` x] + 
  0.00217492761931676` Sinh[0.7873247600956254` x]
b1 = -0.6602544607925729` Cos[1.333653172408094` x] + 
   1.9398920188287387` Cosh[1.333653172408094` x] - 
   0.4735804874591427` Sin[1.333653172408094` x] - 
   1.9399822286723991` Sinh[1.333653172408094` x];
b2 = 3.7823445459113036`*^-6 Cos[1.333653172408094` x] - 
  2.982322047306202`*^-6 Cosh[1.333653172408094` x] - 
  0.33465162006494` Sin[1.333653172408094` x] + 
  0.11389784604237745` Sinh[1.333653172408094` x]
w = 8.14821*^-7 *(Piecewise[{{a1, x <= 4/4}, {a2, x > 4/3}}]) + 
  7.08493*^-8 (Piecewise[{{b1, x <= 4/4}, {b2, x > 4/3}}])
Plot[w, {x, 0, L}]
```

I am trying to plot an equation `w` which is a linear combination of two `piecewise functions` . I don't understand why I am getting the error. I checked the syntax it is correct, apparently one of the answers in the stack overflow for this problem is a typo in plot function. I checked that also no error.
The value of L=4. And the error That I am facing is **{x,0,L} is not a machine-size real number**.

Comment: What is the value of L ?

Comment: What error do you get? Don't make us guess, [edit] your questions and provide all the necessary information. Including the value of `L` , the text of the error and the expected outcome.

Comment: It appears that x would go from 0 to some value > 4/3 say 2. And the plot looks fine with L replaced by 2.

Comment: The value of  L is 4

Comment: @vijay You are already around here for quite some time and you have already asked several questions. By now, you should have learned that you have to add all relevant information _to the question_ and not as comment. Indeed, you can _edit_ your original post to supply additional info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks ok. For me the output I get is something like this:[image]

```
Plot[w, {x, 0, 4}, PlotStyle->{Thick, Red}]
```

Or you can define `L=4;` somewhere in the code.

Comment: I think I committed a typo in my code, I defined L for length as well as defining lagrangian. It's my mistake. Actual code was very long  I could not able to find the mistake by my self. Thanks for your inputs.